# Adding empty array to a JSON object

Tags: java, arrays, json

I am trying to create a JSON object that looks like the below :

`{"filters":
   {"defaultOperator":"OR",
    "filters":[]}}`

What should i add to my JSON object to make a empty array object ??. Cant get my head around an empty array .

tried `jo1.put("filters",new Object[0]);`. This did not work .

I am testing an API which requires these array filled only in special cases, most of the time its empty. But dont know how to add it. I am creating the entry JSON like

```
JSONObject jo1 = new JSONObject();
                 jo1.put("defaultOperator", "OR");
                 jo1.put("filters","[]");

                 jo3 = new JSONObject();
                 jo3.put("filters", jo1);

                 //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),""+jo3.toString() , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                 //json = new GsonBuilder().create().toJson(comment1, Map.class);
                 httppost.setEntity(new StringEntity(jo3.toString()));
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
 JSONArray jarr = new JSONArray();
 jo1.put("filters",jarr);
```

or all on one line:

```
jo1.put("filters", new JSONArray());
```

Comment: Perfect , some times the simple answers do wonders and help code. Thanks a Ton . accepted this one.